# Start a C# web API inside an application

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, console-application, .net-6.0

EDIT :

I found this question : [Simple routing with web server in netcore console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56981304/simple-routing-with-web-server-in-netcore-console-app) so I tried to do something with it.

I created a console application with the following code (basically the same as in the answer but with minor changes) :

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StartServer(args);
    }

    public static void StartServer(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}

public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(configure => configure.MapControllers());
    }
}

public class MyEndpoint : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("")]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "it works";
    }
}
```

This works fine. If I call the `StartServer` method from another project (another console app), it still works.

But then I replaced the code with the new .NET 6 style :

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StartServer(args);
    }

    public static void StartServer(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

        var app = builder.Build();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.MapControllers();
        app.Run();

    }
}

public class MyEndpoint : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("")]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "it works";
    }
}
```

And that works if I start the server from its own project, but not anymore (404 error) if it is started from the other console app.

What am I missing ?

========== ORIGINAL POST ==========

I am currently learning web development in C#, and specifically trying to make a C# REST API that can be accessed and started from another assembly in .NET 6.

If you need more context : The idea behind all this is to add a web API to an existing large program. The API would have a class holding data received from the application, and sent as request responses to the API clients.

This is what I tried :

First, I created a Web API project with the Visual Studio 2022 template, set its output type to "Class Library" instead of "Console Application", and then put all its Program.cs content inside a separate class ("Starter.cs") and static method ("Start"). Then, I created a separate console application, referenced the API project, and called the Starter.Start method.

The server actually starts : it is visible in the console output, and I can access it with my browser.

The problem is that I only have a blank page, the controller is not called at all when I try to access the URL that otherwise works when the API it started as a console application.

Is there something I am missing ? Config files that are not read when the app starts that way (appsettings.json ?) ?
Or is this a stupid way of doing what I want to achieve ? If so, don't hesitate to tell me a better solution, as I said I'm just learning web so I don't really understand/know all the good practices and architectural do's and don'ts yet.

Here is the code I modified, nearly nothing.

Code that was in Program.cs (now deleted) :

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Starter
    {
        public static void Start(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            builder.Services.AddControllers();

            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

            var app = builder.Build();

            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

And how I call it in the console app :

`WebApplication1.Starter.Start(args);`

after which there is a `Console.ReadLine();` to prevent the app from closing.

The rest is basically the same code as in the Visual Studio 2022 Web API project template in .NET 6.

Comment: It's unclear what the question is. Why don't you just create a new project using the `webapi` or `web` template instead of copying code from questions that may or may not be relevant? The code in the question isn't helping - it's the same as the template code with different method names

Comment: The only question seems to be `make a C# REST API that can be accessed and started from another program` which is itself unclear (the `in .NET 6` part isn't important). What do you mean started from another program? The only way to start one program from another is to call `Process.Start()` pointing to that executable, passing the necessary arguments. Or do you want to use the console app a class library?

Comment: If you want to call the setup code from another application, refactor your code and extract what you want to call into public classes and methods. Once you do that you'll be able to add a reference to another project and use those classes

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos
Yes sorry, I meant "started from another assembly", not "program". I'll change that in the question.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I think the "NET 6" part is in fact relevant because it seems that the way of starting a Web API is different than what was done in NET 5. If you look at the "Edit" part, you'll see 2 blocks of code. The first one is a "NET 5 way" of starting the server. When I do that, I can access my endpoint (from a browser for example) if I start it (calling StartServer) from another assembly. But that is not the case if I use the code of the second block, which otherwise works fine if I execute it from its own assembly (through the Main)

Comment: There's no `StartServer` in the Web API .NET templates, nor is one needed. The question you link to isn't relevant. .NET 6 or not, the only way to allow code to be called from another project is to put it in a public class, in a public method. That's what you need to do if you want to put the Web API code in a separate assembly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ms recomends this syntax for net 6 minimal apis https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0

```
app.MapGet("/MyEndpoint", () =>
{
   return "it works";
});
```

as an example, I am using this in my apis , when I am testing them from Visual Studio since I don't like  an empty screen.

At first I change launchSettings.json

```
....
"launchUrl": "welcome",
"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
....
```

and this is my welcome code

```
app.MapGet("/welcome", () =>
{
  var con = "<html><body><h1>Hello!</h1><p> <h3>  API Is Ready To Work!!! </h3> </p></body></html>";
  
  return Results.Content(con, "text/html");
});

app.Run();
```

Comment: "ms recomends this syntax" - 1) no, it does not, 2) it is not just syntax.

Comment: @GuruStron you can check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @Serge and? I've read this documentation and still do not see where it is "recommended". And again - it is not just a syntax, it is completely new pipeline which coexists with traditional controllers and has some advantages (mainly performance and simplicity) and downsides (it is far less powerful in terms of features out of the box and due to the goals of minimal apis it is not supposed to catch up).

Comment: @GuruStron I am sorry , i just tryed to use some polite words. I could use another words as well. But this forum is not about lingvistics

Comment: @Serge _"But this forum is not about lingvistics"_ - totally agreed. It is about helping and providing quality information.

Comment: @GuruStron maybe you are right, the answer was too short. I like when  an answer  has only code, i don't want to waste my time for reading,  but I suspect not everybody likes it.  So I added some more explanations to my code.